# How Do I Use A Function in Main?

Tags: function, if-statement, char

I'm stuck in my program. I need help using a function in the main method. So far I have this:

```
    double x, y;
    char op;

    System.out.print("X: ");
    x = keyboard.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("Y: ");
    y = keyboard.nextDouble();

    System.out.print("Enter Operation: ");
    op = keyboard.next().charAt(0);

    do
    {   
        if (op == '+');
            System.out.print("..");

    }
    while (op != 'q');

    System.out.print("Bye!");
}

public static double sum (double x, double y)
{
    double sum = 0;
    sum = (x + y);

    return sum;
}
public static double minus (double x, double y)
{
    double minus = 0;
    minus = (x - y);

    return minus;
}
public static double multiply (double x, double y)
{
    double multiply = 0;
    multiply = (x * y);

    return multiply;
}
public static double divide (double x, double y)
{
    double divide = 0;
    divide = (x/y);

    return divide;
}
```

For the "if statement" I want to use the functions. If the operation is '+' then it would use the sum function to add x and y. But how do I type it in the "if statement"?
Sorry. It's my second programming class so I'm still learning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You call another function something like this:

```
double output = sum(1,3);
```

Even more generally, it goes something like this:

```
OutputType VariableToHoldOutput = MethodName(Parameter1, Parameter2, etc);
```

With the output being optional to store. If the output type is void, you cannot even store it. That would result in something like this

```
MethodName(Parameter1, Parameter2, etc);
```

ALSO, an `if` statement is not followed by a semicolon. The way you have it is equivalent to:

```
if (op == '+')
{
    ;
}
System.out.print("..")
```

You probably want something more like:

```
if(op == '+')
{
    double output = sum(X,Y);
    System.out.print("Output = " + output);
}
```

Comment: So I put double output = sum(x,y); ? In the "if statement" 
When I do it runs this:
X: 5
Y: 5
Enter Operation: +

and doesn't do the function. 
Sorry for not understanding the concept..

Comment: I see the problem, remove the semicolon after the if, although it still should work. I will update my answer

Comment: I'm sorry I can't upvote the answer it says I need 15 reputation. I'll accept it as an answer and when I reach 15 reputation I'll upvote it. Promise! :)